# Extracting Related XML Component

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I've got the below XML where I'm successfully exporting all the values from the cmpD nodes. Where I'm getting stuck however, is how can I extract the related `<bend>` values that appear within the appropriate `dtl` node.

Here is the current result being produced:

**Current Result**

```
cmp cmpAmt  cmpCode
B   1       A
C   9       A
G   2       A
F   1       A
F   1       L
```

and here is what I'm trying to get the result as but with the appropriate `<bend>` value within `<Dtl>`.

Anyone know how this could be done?

**Expected Result**

```
cmp cmpAmt  cmpCode    bend
B   1       A          A 
C   9       A          A 
G   2       A          A
F   1       A          Z
F   1       L          Z
```

What I have currently:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '
            <Dtl>
                <Type>R</Type>          
                <bend>A</bend>
                <cmpD>
                    <cmp>B</cmp>
                    <cmpAmt>1</cmpAmt>
                    <cmpCode>A</cmpCode>
                </cmpD>
                <cmpD>
                    <cmp>C</cmp>
                    <cmpAmt>9</cmpAmt>
                    <cmpCode>A</cmpCode>
                </cmpD>
                <cmpD>
                    <cmp>G</cmp>
                    <cmpAmt>2</cmpAmt>
                    <cmpCode>A</cmpCode>
                </cmpD>
            </Dtl>
            <Dtl>
                <Type>R</Type>
                <bend>Z</bend>
                <cmpD>
                    <cmp>F</cmp>
                    <cmpAmt>1</cmpAmt>
                    <cmpCode>A</cmpCode>
                </cmpD>
                <cmpD>
                    <cmp>F</cmp>
                    <cmpAmt>1</cmpAmt>
                    <cmpCode>L</cmpCode>
                </cmpD>
            </Dtl>'
```

and the SQL:

```
select 
    b.value('(cmp/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    b.value('(cmpAmt/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    b.value('(cmpCode/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
from
    @XML.nodes('/Dtl/cmpD') AS A(b)
```

Comment: Well avoid trying to use the `..` axis to lookup `bend` elements because that's extremely slow and inefficient. Have you tried selecting the common `/Dtl` parent nodes first and then cross applying the `cmpD` child nodes?

Comment: I haven't no, as I'm not sure how I could Cross Apply into the appropriate Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first shred the `DTL` nodes, then feed that into another `.nodes` using `cross apply` to shred the `cmpD` nodes:

```sql
select
    x2.cmpD.value('(cmp/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    x2.cmpD.value('(cmpAmt/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    x2.cmpD.value('(cmpCode/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    x1.dtl.value('(bend/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
from
    @XML.nodes('/Dtl') x1(dtl)
cross apply x1.dtl.nodes('cmpD') AS x2(cmpD);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aee23f9f3b009b7dc6977047d86090c8)

Note how the second `.nodes` refers to the first, and does *not* use a leading `/`.

> I suggest you rethink the column types and lengths, can they all really need `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlieface, much appreciated, and thanks for mentioning the / , that makes perfect sense.